# Parse Xml text to class in c#

Tags: c#, json, xml, xml-parsing, deserialization

I want to parse below xml text to object of class

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data><Error><![CDATA[No Error]]></Error></data>
```

class :

```
        public class AAA
        {
            public BBB data;
        }

        public class BBB
        {
            public string Error;
        }
```

Code :

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DUserInfo));
                        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlText))
                        {
                            AAA info = (AAA)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
                        }//using
```

Error :

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 40).
<data xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{
"?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "UTF-8"
},
"data": {
    "Error": {
        "#cdata-section": "No Error"
    }
}
}
```

is JSON not XML, So You have deserialize as JSON (not as XML) to `Object`.

Use **`NewtonSoft.Json`** dll to parse this text format.

**Alternatively...** :

Or you can convert your JSON to an actual **[valid xml](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/296560)** first and then convert it to object.

Also you can try some online JSON-to-XML converter :
(pass the result to `AAA info = (AAA)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));`)

Example result from : http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.WCVnky2LQrg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <?xml>
        <@version>1.0</@version>
        <@encoding>UTF-8</@encoding>
    </?xml>
    <data>
        <Error>
            <#cdata-section>No Error</#cdata-section>
        </Error>
    </data>
```

PS:  Please check your class structures too.

Correct Json will be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <Error>
        <cdata-section>No Error</cdata-section>
    </Error>
</data>
```

You classes will be like this.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Error")]
public class Error {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="cdata-section")]
    public string Cdatasection { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="data")]
public class Data {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Error")]
    public Error Error { get; set; }
}
```

You can desialize your xml to object in this way.

```
string xmlText = "your xml";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlText))
    {
        Data info = (Data)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
    }
```

You are doing in wrong way in this line.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DUserInfo));
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit. Felt it was better to just add this extra info to your Answer since it just extends what you said anyway...

Comment: @VC.One thanks for your edit, Its good spirit . It will help the OP.

Comment: @SajjadZare.  are you still facing issue in converting from xml to object?

Comment: @viveknuna yess

Comment: @SajjadZare, what is the expected result? You want a String saying "No Error"? Extracting the value from XmlSerializer's `.data.Error` entry?

Comment: @viveknuna when want to parse go to catch and error is : There is an error in XML document (1, 40).
<data xmlns=''> was not expected.

Comment: @SajjadZare. Updated answer, It will definitely work for you

Comment: @viveknuna  infoss.Error.Cdatasection is Null

Comment: Its working fine for me, there might be something you are missing, please review your code

Comment: @viveknuna  delete { get; set; } and work correctly , thank youuuuuuuu

Comment: thats good, by the way it was working for me even with get set, So I'm just curious to know why its not working for you. Could you please let me know your targeted .net framework and visual studio version.

Comment: visual studio 2010 , .net 4.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127868/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-sajjadzare).